# Lookup Column Value through Rest API

Tags: lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

i have a small requirement, where in i am pulling in a lot of data from List A to List B through Rest API. but i am stuck at one place where in i am not able to pull in lookup value in List B.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `&$expand=[Column internalname]` and the `&$Select=[Column internalname]/Id` url parameter to get the Id of the lookup item, if you need the text value from the lookup use /Title instead of /Id.

I have a lookup to a list, the column name in list which contains the lookup is "Sync", so my REST call is like this:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'1B51700E-D95D-46C5-9B9B-1386CCCC07DB')/items?$select=Title,Sync/Id&$expand=Sync
```

This returns the value from the column "Titel"and the id of the lookup column "Sync".

Comment: Hi ,

i am using this query 'url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'xyz')/items?$select=CP_x0020_Should_x0020_Cost_x0020,Program_x0020_Name_x003a_BU_x002/Title,Planned_x0020_Model_x0020_Close,Actual_x0020_Model_x0020_Close,SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$filter=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id,Program_x0020_Name_x003a_BU_x002",
' 
where in Program_x0020_Name_x003a_BU_x002 is the lookup column. 
Can you help me with this query itself?

Comment: From what I can see the query is just slightly off here: &$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id,Program_x0020_Name_x003a_BU_x002 <-- you don't want the "/Id". You only need to tell which fields you want to expand.

Comment: still did not work.

Comment: I assume the xyz is a placeholder in the above? Did you try it in the browser?

Comment: yup i did but it did not work

Comment: Ok does it work if you remove all fields that needs to be expanded (along with the expand parametre)?

Comment: it works if i remove the lookup column value.

Comment: The lookup columns are normal lookup and not people fields? Did you try replacing the /Title with /Id?

Comment: They are normal lookup columns.  i havent. will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below call to expand columns

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=Title,LookupField1/FieldToBeExpanded1,LookupField2/FieldToBeExpanded2&$expand=LookupField1,LookupField2
```